# Field Validation Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Having some trouble with my form field validation. I have two text field that requires validation before it persists to the next page. The validations are run correctly but the validation messages shows like rails error.

[image]

But I want this error like below[image]

Any one Knows why its shows like rails error.

Model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow

  belongs_to :folder
  belongs_to :employee

  after_initialize :init_start_dateenter code here

  validates_presence_of :folder_id, :employee_id
end
```

Controller:

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
        @assignment.folder.update({status: 'assigned'})
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I have two more forms to validate the fields. In that forms the validation errors are shows correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `!` from the save, as this will throw an error on that line, if you omit the `!` it will simply return a boolean (and then render the error or success.

so

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Assignment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
        @assignment.folder.update({status: 'assigned'})
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks JamesWatling :)  It's my mistake